# Open a popup using on_sent_ok using Contact Form 7 and Ninja Popups?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, popup, contact-form-7, ninja

I am using WordPress with Contact Form 7 and Ninja Popups. I would like to open a popup when the form is sent using CF7's additional settings. I have tried:

```
on_sent_ok: "snp_open_popup(’’,’’,’snppopup-content-POPUPID’,’content’);"
```

(where POPUPID is the ID of the ninja popup that I want to open) which is not working.

Some javascript examples to call a popup using ninja popups:

```
POPUP_ID=’25’ ;snp_open_popup(’’, ’’, ‘snppopup-content-’ + POPUP_ID, ‘content’);
```

or

```
jQuery(“SELECTOR”).click(function(){ return snp_open_popup(’’,’’,’snppopup-content-POPUPIDHERE’,’content’); });
```

This is used with the ninja popup shortcode inside the page/post content: [ninja-popup ID=XX] or

```
onclick=”return snp_open_popup(’’,’’,’snppopup-content-POPUPIDHERE’,’content’); ”
```

and [ninja-popup ID=XX] in the page content.

I figure that with this, there has to be a way to call the popup using the on_sent_ok but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

For Show PopUp
snp_open_popup('','','snppopup-content-7018','content');

For Close PopUp wit TimeOut
setTimeout('_snp_bld_close(7018)',3500);

For Close PopUp 
_snp_bld_close(7018)

Comment: For other readers of your answer to find it useful, I suggest that you add some text explaining it a bit.